# Purpose of using global connection in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

I have been looking at other people's VBA code and have noticed that a lot of people use global connection to set their ADODB connection. From what I have read this is done because opening a new connection is rather slow and can impact the performance speed a lot if there are a lot of connections open and closed.

Having said that, I have also seen people doing

```
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = global_connection
    conn.execute "sql code"
    conn.close
```

Dosen't this defeat the purpose of creating global connection as it is equivalent to creating a new connection? Is there a scenario where this is useful?

Edit 1:

Global connection string is set using

Module 1

```
public SERVERNAME ="MYSERVER"
public DATABASENAME ="DATABASE"
```

Different Module:

```
globalstring = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & SERVERNAME & ";Database=" & DATABASENAME & ";Trusted_Connection=yes;"
global_connection.open globalstring
```

Comment: You need to share the full code, e.g. how global_connection is instantiated, so we can tell you what's actually happening. As-is, this code doesn't open a new connection, but does close one, so that can't be complete.

Comment: Sorry, I added the instantiation code. Tell me if you need more.

Comment: Yes, when is that global code triggered? Currently, `global_connection` is still nothing, how is that defined?